# How best to triangulate these quadded joint patches (e.g. for export to animation program)?

Tags: mesh

I followed [this joint patches video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5Jksu5Z8AA) to triangulate a model which is to be exported to a program that only supports triangulated meshes. It's not a horribly long video, but to save you that time, the demonstrated patches are shown below. You'll notice that they're all quads of some sort, but the program I export these models to only takes triangulated meshes (it will triangulate any quad mesh automatically if given that instead). Is there a similar "best" patch technique that uses only triangles; or what is the best way to triangulate these patches here to simulate real elbow movement?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the “triangulate faces“ operator?

Comment: Admittedly, I have not, and I do know that that exists, but Idk for sure if that's better than whatever the export program (or Blender's own export plugin) does. I just wonder if there's something to know about placing the dividing edge.